# How do I prevent MongoDB replica set from querying the primary?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, replicaset

read-operations-only:

is there a way to have a MongoDB replica set, but to make the MongoDB instance on the box that is connected to, be the MongoDB that gets queried?

I have three EC2 instances behind an AWS load balancer.

on each EC2 instance runs MongoDB, which is part of the replica set.

I have express endpoints on nodeJS and I connect to the replica set as follows

```
 mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3.',
    function (err, db)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            complete('{}');
        }
        else
        {
```

I would like to distribute the load of queries evenly across all three instances of my MongoDB replica set instead of by default having all queries routed to the EC2 instance where my primary MongoDB is defined, because this destroys the point of my load balancer  (which is to balance the load of queries across all three instances evenly).

my understanding is that when connecting to a MongoDB replica set,  that the primary instance is always selected unless the primary instance is down, and therefore the purpose of every secondary instance is just to serve as a backup.

in my example some people would call this HOT,COLD,COLD.  because there are two instances that never get used.

the reason that I would like to have the query load distributed evenly is so my set up can be WARM,WARM,WARM.

there for in the future when the number of users increases, to  keep query performance optimal, I can add more EC2 instances behind the load balancer,  to improve query performance.

and when the data grows, such that a single instance is too slow anymore to return the data on time, that is when I would shard each instance into other EC2 instances.

note:  I would like the source code of every EC2 instance to be the same.  I am using git,  and I would like to easily push and pull source code to every instance in my replica set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [ReadPreference](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/readpreference.html), which will allow you to direct read requests to secondaries. Example code for the MongoDB node.js driver can be seen [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html).

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3./?readPreference=secondary', ...
```

Comment: If I use readpreference=secondary,  and there are two secondaries (one on 2.2.2.2 and one on 3.3.3.3). Do we know if the mongoDB secondary that will get used will be on the machine the load balancer routed to? For example if AWS load balancer routes to box 3.3.3.3 where the endpoint connects to the mongoDB replica set with read preferences set to secondaries, would the secondary chosen also be on 3.3.3.3 ?

Comment: It sounds like NEAREST **should** pick the replica mongoDB from the set that is on the same box - but it's not clear to me  if that is true or how to check

Comment: The driver is not going to know anything about AWS topology or ELBs or anything when computing NEAREST.  It's calculated solely on network latency.  If your client is running on the same instance as a replica set member, it will generally query that, whether it's the primary or a secondary.  But remember, a new primary can get elected at any time, and if you're running with NEAREST, you will not prevent reads from the primary.  Running your app on the same instances as your MongoDB replica set members is generally not a best practice, though.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "running your app on the same instance",  but here is a picture http://motionreboot.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Screen-Shot-2016-06-06-at-9.21.44-AM.png